# Hover is not firing after window resize in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

I'm having an issue with the pseudo-class `:hover` in Google Chrome.

Basically I have an element that when in :hover state it's sibling is displayed. This works fine.

Then I add a media query so that when the viewport has a specific `min-width` the element is no longer displayed but the sibling is.

When going from the min-width to a smaller width the `display:none` on the sibling no longer fires.

It might be easier to understand by taking a look at this example. Try resizing the viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gPGR/1/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="trigger">
  </div>
  <div id="target">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 24px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#trigger {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #275;
}
#target {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f57;
}
#trigger:hover ~ #target {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  #trigger {
    display: none;
  }
  #target {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

This is only an issue in Chrome/Chrome Canary. I have tested in the latest versions of:

- Chrome
- Chrome Canary
- FF
- IE
- Safari
- Opera

Is there something I can do to resolve this or do I just need to stick with javascript for these kinds of interfaces.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that if I force the element state to `:hover` using chrome dev tools it starts working again until the next resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting error, I'm not sure why that happens

I was able to fix the issue by adding an empty `#target:hover { }`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5gPGR/3/)

If you're using a preprocessor that would remove this line, you can add a property that you already have, like `#target:hover { display:block; }`

Comment: Nice hack. Only issue is that when using a pre-processor the unused selector is removed. So this will only work if using plain css.

Comment: You can add a property to it that is already declared like `display:block;` and it will still work